# How do I indicate to powershell that a job failed

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script in which I want it to run multiple processes simultaneously. I want it to fail if any of the jobs fail. So I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
   #do stuff
   if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
   {
      #indicate that the job has failed.
   } 
}
```

How do I indicate that the job has failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To indicate a failed job, try using this command:

```
[System.Environment]::Exit(1)
```

This will show as 'Failed' too, but probably not as good:

```
Throw "the job has failed"
```